# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre localhost de forma correcta?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localhost

Lo que necesito hacer es darle un nombre propio al `localhost` de una máquina Linux (donde se encuentra el servidor Apache con un sistema web) La idea es que este nombre pueda ser resuelto por todas las máquinas de conectadas a la **misma Red Local** [Se trata de una pequeña intranet]. Esto,  para no tener que digitar la IP del servidor. Es decir; si antes tenía que digitar `http://192.168.1.100` en el navegador,  ahora debería poder digitar `http://sistema.home` para desplegar el sistema alojado en la máquina. Antes lo solucionaba digitando el nombre de la máquina con la extensión .home pero muchos usuario se complican escribiendo  `http://Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home` (muy largo y difícil de recordar)

Para esto lo primero que hice fue cambiar el archivo /etc/host dejandolo asi:

```
127.0.0.1       sistema.home
127.0.1.1       Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home
```

Y luego, modifique el servername del archivo /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf :

```
ServerName  sistema.home
```

Luego me di cuenta que de esta forma sólo podía acceder localmente  digitando `http://sistema.home` (solo resolvia si estaba navegando en la misma máquina servidor) por lo que cambié también el nombre de mi máquina a de `Ubuntu-Server-HP-154`  a `sistema` y configure  el archivo  /etc/hostname

```
sistema
```

También hice los correspondientes cambios en  /etc/host  de esta forma:

```
127.0.0.1       sistema.home
127.0.1.1       sistema
```

Reinicios de network, systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed, de Apache, de la Máquina, etc

Pues bien, desde otra maquina sigo sin poder acceder a través de `http://sistema.home`,  pero si puedo a través del antiguo nombre de la máquina `http:// Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home` Es más, cuando hago un `ping -a 192.168.1.100` aún resuelve como `Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home` y no como `sistema.home`

Entonces me puse a revisar la configuración con el comando `hostname` de la máquina servidor:

```
.$ hostname
sistema
```

Perfecto, me dice que el hostname de mi maquina se llama sistema

```
.$ hostname -f 
sistema
```

Perfecto, me dice que el FQDN (Nombre de dominio completo) se llama sistema

```
 .$ hostname -A 
 Ubuntu-server-HP-88454154.home Ubuntu-server-HP-88454154.home
```

¿Qué? Me dice que existen más **FQDN** en mi máquina y se llaman `Ubuntu-Server-HP-154` Pero entonces: ¿Dónde están esos otros FQDN para eliminarlos? ¿Porqué pasa esto? y entonces ¿Cuál es la correcta forma cambiar el nombre localhost para que quede disponible para el resto de la Red Local?

Comment: por un casual tienes en ese servidor un servicio dns montado? si es asi, tienes que cambiarlo en los archivos de configuracion de dicho servicio. Lo mas normal suele ser este caso, y que los otros equipos tengan una resolucion dns contra este equipo. De todas formas, una forma sencilla seria irte a cada uno de los equipos de la red local y poner en su archivo `hosts`el nombre del servidor y su ip. Con eso, cada otro equipo podra conocer a este servidor por el nombre que tengas puesto.

Comment: Independientemente de cómo se llame tu host de manera local, lo importante es qué servicio utilizan tus clientes para resolver nombres en ip's. ¿Es un DNS? ¿un WINS? ¿Dónde reside ese servicio? ¿Se auto-configura? ¿Cada nodo de la red se identifica en el servicio o este se basa en un fichero de configuración? De eso dependerá lo que debes ajustar. Por otro lado, en la parte conceptual, cada equipo, a si mismo siempre se va a identificar como `localhost`. En ese sentido, el nombre `localhost` nunca va a dejar de existir, por más que cambies el nombre del host.

Comment: @Jakala es una máquina con Ubuntu 16.4 común y corriente  no tengo servidor de nombres montado y la verdad que no es la idea ir maquina por maquina cambiando sus archivos host y aunque lo hiciera sería un parche no estaría solucionando este tema.

Comment: @jachguate pensé en eso y se conectan al DNS 8.8.8.8 pero no implicaría en nada ya que en un inicio todos podían acceder mediante el nombre anterior del equipo más la extensión .home [Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home] y si: localhost nunca va a dejar de existir, por más que cambie el nombre del host.. en el mismo servidor, pero el resto de la red no ve Localhost. o bien ve una IP o ve un nombre de Host o ve un nombre de equipo apuntando a un servidor web.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 es el DNS (de Google) que utilizan para resolver nombres externos a la red, pero ¿dentro de la red local, cómo resuelven los nombres? Si no lo sabes, sospecho que es NetBios/WINS. Dale una mirada a https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order

Comment: Gracias @jachguate pero creo que el problema es que la máquina quedó con los FQDN antiguos ya que en una red local se puede apuntar el nombre del equipo al servidor web. es lo que te decía de que antes los usuarios entraban por http://Ubuntu-Server-HP-154.home al sistema web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fichero /etc/hosts no tiene efectos a nivel de resolucion de nombres para herramientas como 'host' o 'nslookup', para otros efectos tendrias que revisar la configuracion en nsswitch.conf que es donde se determina el orden de busqueda a otros niveles.

De todas maneras, si los sistemas que siguen encontrando el servidor con su antiguo nombre son Linux, es posible que tengas algun proceso activo que hace cache en el sistema como podrian ser nscd o dnsmask.

Podrias resetear la cache de cualquiera de estos procesos de estar activos reiniciandolos con systemctl, tipo

```
systemctl restart nscd
```

o

```
systemctl restart dnsmask
```

Si los hosts que siguen viendo el antiguo registro dns son Windows, puede ser tambien por cache, tendrias que poder ver la cache en estos sistemas con:

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

Para limpiar la cache en estos sistemas windows tendrias que ejecutar:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Buena. Lo de systemctl restart nscd y ipconfig -flushdns me hizo el día. Gracias.